# How can I identify kind of variable I'm trying to compare in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, integer, boolean

How to identify kind of varible, I'm trying to compare in JavaScript?
I just have always the same problems in JavaScript with the kind of varibles, like

- int
- String
- boolean
- float
- object

so many times i have to use

- Boolean(String) - to boolean variable
- Number(String) - to int or float varible
- String.toString() - to String variable

the problem is when I use to compare [(value==true)], when the variable is not boolean or when I try to compare with others values [(value==varible)]

so there is a way to know what kind of variable is?
a way to know the type of value

Comment: The source code is part of the source code of the interpreters. Happy digging, and that's only possible with the open-source ones. The only thing you really need is a proper documentation of their behavior anyway.

Comment: you can use `typeof(variable)`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by checking the type of a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [Himal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189040/himal) say use typeof.. so I can found the answer

```
var myvar=5
alert(typeof myvar);
 //alerts "number"
```

so to know kind of varible use `typeof`

source : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml